# Composite C1 - Membership Provider - Simple Registration and Login

Tags: membership-provider, c1-cms

I am developing my first application using the Composite C1 CMS as the core system. I am currently working my way through the documentation and learning about data structuring, etc. I see that there is a paid Extranet package which can be purchased but I would prefer to develop my own Membership system within the site.

What would be the best way for me to allow users to register on the front end of my Composite C1 website and then to allow them access to a password protected area once they have registered and logged in?

I am a fairly experienced .net developer but Composite C1 is very new to me (at first impressions I like it a lot!)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the commercial Extranet package you can write a RenderingResponseHandler plugin and register it it the ~/App_Data/Composite/Composite.config file.

Check the guide ["How can I validate users before a page or media file is being served?"](http://docs.composite.net/ASP-NET/ASPNETFAQ?q=How%20can%20I%20validate%20users%20before%20a%20page%20or%20media%20file%20is%20being%20served?)

RenderingResponseHandler plugins are tasked with approving page and media requests and they can either let the request pass or redirect the request to a new URL.

You would need to take care of the user data base and login page yourself. Also some mechanism that would allow a user of the cms to mark pages as protected/public might make sense.

There is relevant pointers on the CodePlex thread ["Restricting access to MediaArchive files"](http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/359276#post847855)

Comment: Updated the public API with some relevant bits; http://api.composite.net/html/T_Composite_Core_WebClient_Renderings_Plugins_RenderingResponseHandler_IDataRenderingResponseHandler.htm - the code here work with 3.x and up.